# Add global spell ignore words

Tags: spell-checking, spelling

I'm editing a wiki and it uses *atleast* two languages. Vim has no problem, as it allows multiple languages in spellcheck.

Problem is, some wiki templates, and html-like mediawiki tags are often words that do not exist in any dictionary.

I obviously don't want to add them to any one specific dictionary because it seems suboptimal (and process would be multiplied for every language), and I don't want to `zG` them every time, so I'm asking is there any way to make a personal "wiki" spell list I will call as needed so vim doesn't report markup code as misspells?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sad that this has no answers ): It looks like you can make a custom language dictionary using :mkspell (see `:h spell-mkspell`), maybe you can create a dummy language and add the tags to that dummy language?